# How do I reuse or ensure only one JasperViewer exists at a time?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating a java desktop application. In the application I generate report using [dynamic report](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dynamicreport/) and based on some parameter the report will generate. The user generates the first report and it is then displayed in a jasper viewer. The user minimizes the jasper viewer and generates next report. It is then viewed in a new jasper viewer.

So each time the user generates a report a new jasper viewer is created. How do I reuse or ensure only one JasperViewer exists at a time?

```
JasperPrint print=report.toJasperPrint();
JasperViewer.viewReport(print, false);
```

After that I created object for jasperviewer.

```
JasperViewer jv;
 JasperPrint print;
public void action()
{
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                       @Override
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                          try
                          {
                             report.addColumn(...);
                               ...
                               ...
                              print=report.toJasperPrint();
                           jv=new JasperViewer(print,false);
                           jv.setVisible(true);
                          }
                        });
                 }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to start off, you sample code does not compile. Once formatted correctly, you see that the closing parenthesis and semicolon happen to soon. It should look like:

```
JasperViewer jv;
JasperPrint print;
public void action() {
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      try {
        report.addColumn(...);
        ...
        ...
        print=report.toJasperPrint();
        jv=new JasperViewer(print,false);
        jv.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Now to the question. `JasperViewer` extends `JFrame` and as such any tricks to close it programatically should also work for `JasperViewer`. Since you are storing a reference to the `JasperViewer`, you could check if it is already initialized. If it is send a window event to it to close it.

```
if (jv != null && jv.isVisible()) {
    WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(jv, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
}
```